# Parsing xlsx files with unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, xlsx, exceldatareader

I use the following code to parse an `XLSX` file.

```
private IExcelDataReader GetExcelDataReaderForFile(string filePath)
{
    FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // Create the excel data reader
    IExcelDataReader excelReader;

    excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    // Close the stream
    stream.Close();

    // First row are columns names
    excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

    return excelReader;
}
```

Im running this code on my android. The path is subjective to `Application.persistentDataPath`.  The problem here is that Im getting the following strange error,

> Access to the path "/tmp" is denied.

How do I sort it out? or is there any other ways to parse xlsx files in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting a file/directory at the root of the drive.

You should use `./tmp` (notice the .) or if you insist `Application.persistentDataPath + "/tmp"`

Comment: Correct, but you are trying to access that path with `filePath`
So the error is not with the code you show, it's with the code you do not show.